# Как проверить адаптивность верстки?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Сделала для сайта адаптивную верстку под ширину экрана меньше 400 пикселей. Открываю в Safari с Iphone 5 (реальное устройство), все работает идеально. Когда захожу на специальные сайты, где можно посмотреть внешний вид сайта на разных устройствах, при ширине 320 пикселей (как раз айфон 5) не работает ничего! Почему это может быть?

[image: Вот так с айфона]

[image: Вот так, когда пытаюсь открыть на сайте, указав размер экрана айфона]

Comment: Подозреваю, что meta viewport вам надо добавить в `head` - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Comment: Показывайте html и css ваши, хотя бы в упрощенном варианте.

Comment: Может адаптивность через JS местами сделана, а сайты-анализаторы по какой-то причине не отрабатывают ваши скрипты?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev добавлен...

Comment: @tutankhamun адаптивность колонки сетки bootstrap + media в css. Ну и навигация бутстраповская

Comment: @Visman меня не забанят, если ссылку кину? :) Проект лежит на хостинге уже. Или лучше код к вопросу прикрепить?

Comment: Вместо фраз "все работает идеально" и "не работает ничего" напишите конкретнее.

Comment: @tutankhamun я скрины добавила в вопрос. Первый скрин - как с телефона у меня в сафари открывается. Второй скрин - как на сайте, когда указываю размер экрана айфона

Comment: Не советую доверять сторонним сайтам, для проверки адаптпции сайта существуют встроенные инструменты в браузере

Comment: @БалунВладимир инструменты разработчика в хроме тоже через раз работают, один раз нормально отобразилось, при перезагрузке страницы съехало :(

Comment: В DevTools до 400px все отображается нормально, а вот дальше все ломается из за фиксированой ширины елементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел ваш `responsive.css`, вы там используете для адаптива медиа запрос `max-device-width`, он определяет ширину экрана устройства, а не браузера (если точнее, области рендеринга), используйте `max-width`